# How to get particular rows data in form again to edit

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get particular row's data in form again in particular text filed for edit as my code gives me all rows data in form, how can i get particular rows data when i click particular rows button. Actully when i click edit button it adds two rows data and than display it into form again

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        var count         = 1;
        $("#submit_Button").on('click',function()
        {       
            var fname_Field   = $("#fname1").val();
            var lname_Field   = $("#lname1").val();
            var address_Field = $("#address1").val();


            if($("#fname1").val() == null ||$("#fname1").val() == "" && $("#lname1").val() == null ||$("#lname1").val() == "" && $("#address1").val() == null ||$("#address1").val() == "" )
            {
                alert("Please fill the form");
            }           

            $(".above_Info").append('<tr class="tr_Number"><td id="count_Field">'+count+'</td><td class="first_Name">'+fname_Field+'</td><td class="last_Name">'+lname_Field+'</td><td class="addr">'+address_Field+'</td><td id="button_Edit"><input type="button" name="edit" class="edit_Button"  value="Edit"/></td></tr>');
            count++;
        });




        $(document).on('click',".edit_Button",function()
        {   
            var row     = $("#tbl > tbody > tr").length;        
            var fname   = $("#tbl").find(".first_Name").text();                 
            var lname   = $("#tbl").find(".last_Name").text();              
            var addrs   = $("#tbl").find(".addr").text();       
            var x       = $("#fname1").val(fname);      
            var y       = $("#lname1").val(lname);  
            var z       = $("#address1").val(addrs);                
        });
    });

    </script>
    <style>
    .form{margin-left:200px;
    }

    #address1{margin-left:25px;}
    #fname1, #lname1{margin-left:9px;
    }
    #submit_Button{
        margin-left:95px;
    }    
    .above_Info{margin-left:200px;
                 width:auto;
                 height:auto;
                 border:1px solid #000;
    }   
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="myForm" class="form">
    First Name :<input type="text" name="fname"   id="fname1"   /><br />
     Last Name :<input type="text" name="lname"   id="lname1"   /><br />
       Address :<input type="text" name="address" id="address1" /><br /><br /><br />
    <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="submit_Button" />
    </form>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <table class="above_Info" id="tbl">
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this in `$(this)` context of the clicked button:

```
$(document).on('click',".edit_Button",function(){ 
    // var row     = $("#tbl > tbody > tr").length; 
    var $tr     = $(this).closest("tr");       
    var fname   = $tr.find(".first_Name").text(); 
    var lname   = $tr.find(".last_Name").text();              
    var addrs   = $tr.find(".addr").text();
    $("#fname1").val(fname);      
    $("#lname1").val(lname);  
    $("#address1").val(addrs);                
});
```

---

As per your new comment you have to empty the inputs on doc ready like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fname1, #lname1, #address1").val(''); 

    // all other code as is.

});
```

Comment: how do i get empty fields when i click on submit as in this code it gets submited but those values does not get vanish

Comment: on doc ready just fill the blank values: `$("#fname1, #lname1, #address1").val(''); `

Comment: could you please elaborate. where should i write this at the end or at the ready function?

Comment: @Shanky its your time to elaborate more. your last comment is not helping to understand what happend.

Comment: @Shanky Actually this is a new question so better to ask a new one. As this answer was for a diff question. I hope you get it.

Comment: ok no problm. When i fill all three textboxs after that when i click submit button than it should submit to table and those values which are in textboxs should get vanish

Comment: @Shanky well!!!! form submission actually does a postback so if you add the line there then that should work. but it seems something else is also happening or there might be other code which is not letting it empty.